# How does chrome assign interpreted javascript functionality to its widgets?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8, interpreter

I have been looking closely into **web browers** and the **v8 engine**. I understand the concept of G.U.I and how its possible to dynamically change the G.U.I in your applications on the go, but the confusion of the  v8 engine comes when I start to think about **how can the google chrome application modify the events that are assigned to these new widgets since the chrome application is already compiled?** From what I know about programs: you would need to include the functionality(instructions) inside of the source code in order to dynamically assign events to any widget(that is called by the os) since the web views that we see inside of the browers is apart of the chrome program , the interpreted javascript has to be registered to the chrome program some how. Any resources on this topic is greatly appreciated. Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: Yes, Chrome includes instructions for all possible event types that JavaScript requires. There's no need to hardcode them though, one can dynamically enable/disable them, the source code only needs the *capability* to do that.

Comment: I'd assume that the whole Chrome window is just one "widget" to the OS, and all event routing happens internally. Is it that what you're looking for?

Comment: I figured ,  but I am still puzzled about the mapping of what created widget co-relate to what function ect. I am guessing that the html on click attributes control what widget points to what block of code and ect.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [how browsers work](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/) and [event bubbling/capturing](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)